# python mysql api apostrophe

Tags: python, code-injection, mysql-python, apostrophe

It's known that Python's cgi.escape() function does not escape quotes or the apostrophe.  Can the same be said for the Python MySQLdb API?
In the case below is the apostrophe in O'Reilly escaped on entering the database?

```
lastname = O'Reilly
cursor.execute ('INSERT INTO table_name (surname) VALUES (%s)', (lastname,))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is (and answers need to be at least 30 characters).

Comment: I like your answer very much!  Could I bug you to suggest some documentation?  I believe I've scoured the web for such but you must have found something I missed.  Thanks!

Comment: I've been doing database access for 15 years, so this comes from experience -- it's just the way all database libraries work :-)  What you're doing in the execute() call, is binding the marker (`%s`) to the parameter.  There is no escaping involved (at least conceptually -- you should ignore what the MySQLdb library does under the hood...)

Comment: Ha ha, I guess that,s my problem;  I want to know what Python does under the hood when it comes to sanitizing data.  You're saying that O'Reilly becomes O"&#x27;Reilly or O\\\'Reilly or something en route to the db table?  So then if I call that data for use in an html document I have no further escaping to do?  In your years of coding have you ever seen any Python documents that address that?  I do appreciate your answers.

Comment: No, `O'Reilly` is stored exactly like that in the database table. When the database library implements parameter binding the way the DB-api intended, nothing happens to `O'Reilly` -- at all.  Unfortunately, there are a couple of DB-libs in Python that are (or have been) "faking" parameter binding, and actually doing conversion of the parameters to string before creating the sql statement in the client.  That is not how it's supposed to work though, so I would forget about the exceptions (they will then use the appropriate conversion for the sql-dialect).

Comment: The answer to the question about use in an html document: no further escaping is necessary because of apostrophes (you might need to escape other characters though, e.g. `<` to `&lt;` etc.)